# регулярное выражение для замены в cssText заданного параметра

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть `cssText` вида: `opacity: 0.0751353; width: 0.957432px; height: 3.40888px; margin: 7.70343px; padding: 1.12222px;`.
В нем мне нужно регулярным выражением быстро заменять значение нужного мне css параметра. Вот что у меня вышло:

```
let props = {
    opacity: Math.random(),
    width: Math.random() * 10 + 'px',
    height: Math.random() * 10 + 'px',
    margin: Math.random() * 10 + 'px',
    padding: Math.random() * 10 + 'px'
};

let CSSText = a.style.cssText;

console.log(CSSText);

if (CSSText) {

    for (let key in props) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log('/(' + key+ ':)(\s*)([\w*\s*];)/g');
        console.log(CSSText.search('/(' + key+ ':)(\s*)([^;]*)/g'));
        CSSText.replace('/(' + key + ':)(\s*)([^;]*)/g', props[key]);

    }
}

console.log(CSSText);

a.style.cssText = CSSText;
```

Answer (score 0):

По простому думаю так можно:
`(width:\s)(.+?);` где width - меняете на название нужного парметра. Ну а там дальше реплейс и все такое. Не забывайте дописывать `px`, либо вынести `px` за скобки `(width:\s)(.+?)px;`.